# Преобразовать массив повторяющихся значений (php)

Tags: php

Есть у меня такой незамысловатый массив с повторяющимися значениями:

```
$arr = [
    0 => 29,
    1 => 29,
    2 => 28,
    3 => 27,
    4 => 27,
    5 => 29
  ];
```

задача преобразовать его так, что бы получилось

```
$new_arr = [
   27 => 2,
   28 => 1,
   29 => 3
];
```

В новом массиве кол-во повторяющихся значений становится числом, а ключом становится значение. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто. Надо использовать **[array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php)**

Comment: И это правильный ответ!)

Comment: Если это правильный ответ - прими его.

Comment: @YummyCocktail ↑↑↑  правильно пишут))

Comment: странно, вроде нажал) Сорри))